# Docusaurus: add custom button to code block?

Tags: docusaurus

I’m testing to use Docusaurus for a tutorial and documentation site. I want to customize the code block in markup (md or mdx) to for example add an edit button inside the code block that will open the code in plnkr.

*My question is, how can I add a button (or several buttons) in the code block and add click events to the buttons?*

I have tested Eleventy https://www.11ty.dev/ recently and in that I used `markdown-it-attrs` to add attributes in markdown.

```js
const markdownIt = require("markdown-it");
const markdownItAttrs = require("markdown-it-attrs");
```

and then in the markdown I could add attributes to a code block indicating if that should have an edit button or not.

````
```js {edit=yes}
let a = 2;
console.log(a);
```
````

And then in a script find this code block and add a button and an event listener.

```js
.hasAttribute("edit")
```

```js
.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `<button style="float: right;" class="code_edit">Edit</button>`);
```

```js
.addEventListener("click", () => {
```

I have tried doing something similar in Docusaurus by adding a script in `docusausrus.config.js`

```js
scripts: [{ defer: true, src: "/mycustom.js" }],
```

I can see that this script is added in the head but the script can’t find any html elements. I don’t know where to start with adding attributes to the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it by swizzle https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling the codeblock. Swizzling is essentially just copying the default source code from Docusaurus library into your project and Docusausrus will automatically use your edited codeblock code instead of the default.

First I tried to swizzle the entire codeblock.

```
npm run swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic CodeBlock -- --eject
```

but that broke the live code editor https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/code-blocks#interactive-code-editor that I also want to use. It became a normal codeblock.

Then I swizzled the codeblock with wrap.

```
npm run swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic CodeBlock -- --wrap
```

But then I had problem positioning the new edit button nicely.

Then I swizzled only the content part.

```
npm run swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic CodeBlock/Content -- --eject
```

This did not break the live editor and it was easy to position the new edit button next to the copy button. I edited the files `String.js` and `styles.modules.css`.

In the markup file I then can use an `edit` attribute.

````
```js edit
let a = 1;
console.log(a);  
```
````

and in `String.js` I look for this attribute.

```js
{(metastring ?? "").includes("edit") && <button onClick={handleEditCode}>Edit</button>}
```